# If a pod is restarting because file of required by the service is missing, how can I check whether file exists?

Tags: kubernetes

so I created a volume from secret, contains some file `client.crt`, `ca.crt`, `client.key`
then mount it on `/etc/db-cfg`, something like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "db-config" {
  metadata {
    name      = "db-config"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace_v1.ns.metadata.0.name
    labels    = {
      "sensitive" = "true"
    }
  }

  data = {
    "client.crt" = var.db_ssl_cert
    "client.key" = var.db_ssl_key
    "ca.crt"     = var.db_ssl_root_cert
  }
}

# inside pod:

resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "xx-worker" {
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_namespace_v1.ns,
    kubernetes_secret_v1.db-config
  ]

  metadata {
    name      = "xx-worker-deployment"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace_v1.ns.metadata.0.name

    labels = {
      tier = "xx-worker"
    }
  }

  spec {
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        tier = "xx-worker"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          tier = "xx-worker"
        }
      }

      spec {
        volume {
          name = "xx-db-volume"
          secret {
            secret_name = kubernetes_secret_v1.db-config.metadata.0.name
            items {
              key  = "client.crt"
              path = "client.crt"
            }
            items {
              key  = "client.key"
              path = "client.key"
            }
            items {
              key  = "ca.crt"
              path = "ca.crt"
            }
          }
        }

          volume_mount {
            name       = "xx-db-volume"
            mount_path = "/etc/db-cfg"
            read_only  = true
          }

...
```

but when pod started it reported that `sslmode=require sslcert=/etc/db-cfg/client.crt sslkey=/etc/db-cfg/client.key sslrootcert=/etc/db-cfg/ca.crt: failed to configure TLS (unable to load cert: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input)`

how can I be sure that file exists when pod keep restarting? I cannot `kubectl exec` inside the pod.

**UPDATE**: ok already found the issue, the issue is the file content, not missing file. But the question still stands, just in case some similar problem occured in the future.

Comment: You can update the pod manifest to run something like `sleep inf` instead of the regular command. This allows the pod to start so that you can `kubectl exec` into it and inspect the filesystem.

Comment: that's nice idea :3